# About the behavior of countably additive vector measures

Tags: measure-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space, let $\Sigma$ be a sigma algebra, and let $\mu: \Sigma \rightarrow X$ be a set function. Call $\mu$ "countably additive" if for all disjoint $A_1, A_2 \dots \in \Sigma$, we have:

$$\mu(\bigcup_n A_n) = \sum_n \mu(A_n)$$

and the sum on the right converges (not necessarily absolutely). This condition is equivalent to the following: $\mu$ is finitely additive and whenever $E_1 \supset E_2 \supset \dots$ is a sequence of decreasing sets in $\Sigma$ and $\bigcap_n E_n = \varnothing$, then $\lim_n \mu(E_n) = 0$.

I want to know if the following stronger claim is true: whenever $E_1 \supset E_2 \supset \dots$, then

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{A \subset E_n} |\mu(A)| = 0 \tag{*}$$

**My progress**

This claim (*) is true for $X = \mathbb{R}$. Thus (for general $X$), for all $\phi: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we have:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{A \subset E_n} |\phi (\mu (A))| = 0$$

However, this isn't enough to conclude that (*) true, and I'm beginning to doubt whether it is.

Thanks!

Comment: Whn you mean "the sum of the right converges" you mean it absolutely converges?

Comment: I mean that the partial sums converge as elements of $X$. They do not have to converge absolutely.

Comment: @Theone I think they do converge absolutely, because you can take a permutation of the disjoint elements $\{A_1, A_2, \dots\}$ and the left hand side still has the same value, showing that every permutation of the sum on the right converges to the same value and this implies absolute convergence.

Comment: Also, you say "this is equivalent to $\mu$ being finitely additive". No it is not.

Comment: @QuantumSpace, I fixed the sentence that on finite additivity. Hopefully it is clear now what I mean: countable additivity is equivalent to finite additivity AND a limit.

Comment: @QuantumSpace no, in a general normed space a series which is unconditionally convergent need not be absolutely convergent. See for instance the series $\sum e_n/n$ in $l^\infty$

Comment: @AitorIribarLopez Yes, I thought the measure was real valued haha. Of course you are right.

Comment: In $(*)$ do you mean to assume that $\bigcap E_n=\emptyset$? Doesn't make much sense otherwise. Who told you it was true for $X=\Bbb R$? $E_n=[n,\infty)\subset\Bbb R$ is the standard counterexample

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Good point. I do assume that $\bigcap E_n = \varnothing$ in the claim (*). The case for $X = \mathbb{R}$ can be reduced (by taking positive and negative parts) to the case where $\mu$ is a finite positive measure, and the claim is true when $\mu$ is a finite positive measure.